# RMarkdown conditional formatting with kable()

Tags: r, html-table, formatting, r-markdown, kable

I have the following table:

```
|name|Tin|Tout|Hin|Hout|DT min/2|alpha|
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|water|20   |15   |2.33 |0    |5    |1    |
|waste|15   |20   |0    |2.12 |5    |1    |
|air  |20   |15   |0.03 |0    |5    |1    |
|wast |15   |20   |0    |0.03 |5    |1    |  
|co2  |15   |20   |0    |0.45 |5    |1    |
```

And the following number, declared in another chunk.

```
pinch = 16
```

I would like to highlight in red all the rows for which `Tin < pinch < Tout`. I know in this example it is the case for all rows, however I have many other tables like this and I would like to automate this process.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

I tried looking for other solutions to similar problems, however I found it quite hard to adapt said solutions to my problem, as they were too specific. Plus, I don't have much knowledge with R yet to understand the code written by others.

This would help me greatly !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `kableExtra` and `dplyr` as in the following code. This assumes your data is in a data frame.

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

dfs <- "name|Tin|Tout|Hin|Hout|DT_min2|alpha
water|20   |15   |2.33 |0    |5    |1
waste|15   |20   |0    |2.12 |5    |1
air  |20   |15   |0.03 |0    |5    |1
wast |15   |20   |0    |0.03 |5    |1
co2  |15   |20   |0    |0.45 |5    |1"

df <- read.table(text=dfs, sep='|', header=T)
pinch <- 16

red <- 
    df %>% 
    mutate(red = ifelse(Tin < pinch & pinch < Tout, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
    mutate(row=row_number()) %>%
    select(red, row)

kable(df) %>% kable_styling(full_width = T) %>% row_spec(red$row[red$red], color='red')
```

The dataframe called `red` uses `ifelse` to work out the row numbers to colour red in the call to `kableExtra::row_spec`.

[image]